# Disable the jsgrid's edit and delete button for particular rows

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jsgrid

I want to disable (not to hide) edit and delete buttons for the particular records listed in jsgrid. For example, when ID is 3 (selected from the dropdown), the buttons should be disabled. Is it possible to set configurations for particular records.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/yLf21191/    In this,we can edit the records which doesnot have editable and deletable buttons.Can we disable the "editing" for that particular record?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, redefine `rowClick` (http://js-grid.com/docs/#rowclick) config to call default implementation if an item is editable:

```
rowClick: function(args) {
    if(args.item.Editable) {
        jsGrid.Grid.prototype.rowClick.call(this, args);
    }
},
```

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1s9rpr1y/.

Comment: how to change the image icons? for ex, if i want to change the filter icon to customized icon,how to do that? i ve tried to set background-image: url(folderpath); in jsgrid-theme.min.css  under .jsgrid-clear-filter-button class. Its not getting changed with my new icon.

Comment: I can only get the image which contains all the button images. I replaced my customized image and converted into base64 and updated it. Is there any simple way to do that?